# What could be the best way to find Inverse Matrix in SIMD?

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-inverse, inverse, determinants

I've been digging this for a while

To find the inverse matrix, I need to find the determinant of the matrix(correct?)

But only way that i found is to calculate all the matrix using a11 *(a22*a33 - a23*a32) and so on..

Please enlighten me, what could be the best way to find the determinant, so that I can get inverse matrix?

or is there any more efficient way to get inverse matrix without finding the determinant???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding the determinant of a general matrix, you can use an LU decomposition and then, like what [Intel Math Kernel Library](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-c/top/scalapack-routines/scalapack-computational-routines/matrix-inversion-scalapack-computational-routines/p-getri.html) does:

> computes inv(A) by solving the system inv(A)*L = inv(U) for inv(A).

`inv(U)` (U is an *upper triangular matrix*) is easier and more efficient to compute, for example with procedures shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1008675/437222), but it boils down to the determinant of an upper triangular matrix being just the product of its diagonal.

---

And an obligatory reminder: use existing math library if possible, numerical computations like this is very easy to get wrong.